# Office365 authorization for graph API : AADSTS70001

Tags: office365, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

I must have done those steps 200 times during my last integrations, but today it doesn't work.

I have an app in azure AD with graph authorization set up.

I create a sign in url as follows:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8101%2Fintegrations%2F
&prompt=login
&response_type=code&client_id=20xxxxxx-xxx-xxxx..94d3

This code used to work for 2 month for asking office 365 user to log in and get their access and refresh token, for some reason, today it doesn't work anymore, and on office page I got the following error:

```
Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: 8fc051b1-a2e8-493b-806c-158440c21cf3
Timestamp: 2015-12-04 12:58:49Z
AADSTS70001: Application with identifier '20xxxxxx-xxx-xxxx..94d3' was not found in the directory <mylogin>.onmicrosoft.com
```

For information, I do generate the secret ID key AFTER having add the application graph and having set the permissions.

Comment: Self answer: If users from office 365 comes from different domain as the account you use for Azure AD, you will get this error, in this case you need to set your app as multi tenant! Thanks microsoft for not suggesting it in their error message....